# How to override the MUI styles of the version 5 for Pagination Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I'm using MUI of the version 5. I'm having trouble to assess the active button styles of the Pagination component. I hope that somebody can help me, I will show you the current styles and the styles that I want to achieve.
This is the line of code for the Pagination that I`m using

```
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';

 <Pagination count={10} variant='outlined' shape='rounded' color='primary' />
```

**This is the picture of the current styles**

[image]

**This is the picture of the styles I want to achieve**

[image]

And this is the theme in index,js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../src/style.scss';
import Router from './Router';
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['Lato', 'cursive'].join(','),
    h1: {
      fontSize: 50,
      fontWeight: 600,
      lineHeight: '61px'
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: 500,
      lineHeight: '28.8px',
      textAlign: 'left'
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: 30,
      fontWeight: 600,
      lineHeight: '36.6px',
      color: '#2D6FF6'
    },
    subtitle1: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 400,
      lineHeight: '21.96px'
    },
    subtitle2: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 400,
      lineHeight: '24.32px',
      color: '#8A8A8A'
    },
    'body-sm': {
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: 400,
      lineHeight: '16.8px',
      color: '#667085'
    }
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router></Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I hope that anyone will help me to achieve the styles like in the second image, thanks in advance!